# How to use Polymer for live-reloading of code

Tags: gulp, polymer, polymer-1.0, browser-sync

I am using Polymer and reloading changes in files manually. So I tried using using `browser-sync` and also `browser-sync with gulp` but not able to succeed.

I tried two following ways :

1) **npm scripts** in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "polymer serve | npm run watch",
    "watch": "browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8080 --files 'src/*.html, src/*.js, images/*' "
  },
```

Running it using `npm run dev` ,it ran but not able to detect the changes in the file.

2) **Using gulp with browser-sync**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bs = require('browser-sync').create(); 

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    bs.init({
       port : 5000,
        proxy: {
          target : "localhost:8080"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', bs.reload);
});
```

It also ran but not able to detect the changes in `*.html` file which is present in `src` folder.

Can anybody help me why changes of files not being detected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it myself, i was doing one small mistake in `npm scripts`. I have modified as :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "polymer serve --port 8081 | npm run watch",
    "test": "polymer test",
    "watch": "browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8081 --files \"src/**/*.*, index.html, *.js\""
  },
```

Now it is working fine !!

Comment: Also for those looking to auto reload Polymer 2.x element projects using browser-sync use `"watch": "browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8081 --startPath \"components/MY_ELEMENT\" --files \"**/*.html\""`

Comment: With polymer 3 and cli, seems like this should just be in the default generation, who doesn't need this-